# Postgresql: выборка из таблицы в строку в функции

Tags: postgresql, pgsql

Таблица tb три поля: p01, p02, p03 содержит три строки:

```
  p01,int     p02,text     p03,boolean
 --------------------------------------
   111         abc            false
   222         sql            true
   333         xyz            false
```

Как в функции (pgsql) в одну строку получить результат:

```
"1":111, "2":"abc", "3":false, "4":222, "5":"sql", "6":true, "7":333, "8":"xyz", "9":false
```

Если полей много и критично по скорости, как правильно поступают, чтобы получить на клиенте в браузере?
Второй вопрос: можно ли по примеру передать в браузер вот такой набор:

```
111, "abc", false, 222, "sql", true, 333, "xyz", false
```

например, как элементы массива, чтобы, получив через JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) на клиенте, я смог их
поместить в массив. Делал через:

```
arr := ARRAY(SELECT to_json(p01::int) || ',' || to_json(p02::text) || ',' || to_json(p03::boolean) ...
```

но получилось, если поле одно, а для нескольких полей таблицы, - они как один элемент массива.

Comment: Рекомендую вам второй вопрос задать отдельно, так как с первым он связан лишь косвенно.

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, лучше делать на стороне сервера, а не базы данных. Я вижу это так: сервер запрашивает нужные данные из таблицы `tb`, и там уже преобразует данные в требуемый вид для браузера

Comment: Ainar-G, ок сделаю, - если продвинусь по основному вопросу ..

Comment: Andrei Khotko, обычно так и поступаю, думал получить профит по скорости, т.к. по факту там много под-запросов .. крутил json_object(text[]) и json_object(keys text[], values text[]) .. не осилил.